# Meaning of "browser" in Selenium's requested capabilities

Tags: selenium, functional-testing, behat, mink

I am developing functional tests with Behat, Mink and Selenium. I have long been perplexed by the "browser" item included in the Capabilities object that's created with each new session:

```
02:13:48.592 INFO - Got a request to create a new session: Capabilities
[{browser=safari, name=Behat feature suite, browserName=safari, [...] }]
```

As far as I can tell, only "browserName" has any effect - if I set "browserName" to "safari" and "browser" to any other value, then the new session will be created on a node that can run Safari.

So why does Mink include the value? It must surely have some purpose, but I haven't found any documentation explaining it.

Comment: Dear anonymous downvoter: I'd be more than happy to address any issue you have with the question, but if you just drive-by downvote I have no idea what the issue is.

Answer (score 2):

A possible answer would be:

`browser` and `browserName` is the same capability for the browser to use.

If you are using `capabilities` parametter to set up the desired capabilities to use, then the `browserName` has priority.

If you are NOT using `capabilities` parametter you can also setup the browser name by using `browser`.

To get a better picture please take a look to `getConfig` method at `arrayNode('selenium2')` line from `Extension.php` located in vendor > behat > mink-extension > src.

Hope this will help you in getting an answer or at least point you to the right direction.